# Not ignore a file in a sub directory?

Tags: git

I have the following `.gitignore` file

```
*.pyc

project/app/dist/*
project/bin/*
project/etc/*
project/var/*

!README.txt
```

So far so good, most of my `README.txt` files are not being ignored, just like I want it to happen except for `project/ect/downloads/README.txt`. That file, is being ignored. Why is this? And How can I fix this?

If I remember correctly, I can simply add it to my project manually, but I'd like to learn what I am doing incorrectly in ignoring the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git will not search `project/etc/downloads/` for any files because you have configured it to ignore `project/etc/*`. The “unanchored” `!README.txt` pattern is only good for negating the exclusion of entries in directories that will be searched (i.e. directories that have not themselves been excluded).

If you exclude `project/etc/`, Git will never search that directory, so negated exclusions can never apply to its contents (not even one so explicit as `!project/etc/important-file`!—maybe this could be considered a bug?).

However, if you exclude `project/etc/*`, Git will search that directory, and negated exclusions can apply to its contents. A person might realize that the second pattern will always match all files and assign the same meaning to both patterns, but Git, but Git treats them differently.

You might consider `project/etc/` and `project/etc/*` to mean the same thing, but Git treats them differently because it does not “realize” that the second one will match everything in the directory.

So, to get `!README.txt` to apply in `projects/etc/downloads/` you will have to unignore the directory but ignore its contents before the `!README` pattern:

```
project/etc/*

# "unignore, but ignore the immediate contents of" project/etc/downloads
# so that subsequent negated patterns can apply to the immediate contents
!project/etc/downloads/
project/etc/downloads/*

!README.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response! I would have never guessed unignore-ignore/* method :)

Comment: Apologies for pinging an old post, but in nearly a dozen answers on three separate variations on this question here on SO, this is the first truly satisfactory solution I've seen.  Many thanks!

Comment: The ignore list has to be succeded with a `*`. Something like `public/` will still ignore the unignore in the next lines, it has to be `public/*`.

Answer (score 3):

In the .gitignore file, after /project/etc/*, add the 2 lines:

```
!/project/etc/downloads/
/project/etc/downloads/*
```

Comment: Note: these must come before the `!README.txt` pattern for it to have an affect on the exclusion of `project/etc/downloads/*`