# Un-ignore a directory added to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

What I did was to have two branches:

- local
- production

In my `local` branch I have all my asset folders `css`, `js`, and `img`. And in my `production` branch I added them to my `.gitignore` since I want to host those assets elsewhere.

```
css/
img/
js/
```

so these folders aren't visible in the `production` branch anymore. Is there anyway to restore the `img` folder in the `production` branch? I tried removing `img/` from my `.gitignore` and committing but it won't list on my untracked files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing `img/` from your `.gitignore`, you can `git checkout local -- img` to check out the files from the *local* branch (assuming you are on the *production* branch). They should automatically be staged (otherwise just stage them yourself), and commit them to your *production* branch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:  [Not ignore a file in a sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170137/not-ignore-a-file-in-a-sub-directory)

It should work for the folder as well