# Can't unignore certain file in ignored directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have `.gitignore` like this

```
**/my-site/components/*
```

So I ignore the `/components` folder completely. Okay, I just hacked a file inside of this folder, can I unignore it?

```
!**/my-site/components/com_content/models/articles.php
```

Hmm... that doesn't work. Let's try this.

```
!**/my-site/components/com_content/models/*
```

That doesn't work too. Curious. Maybe this one will work?

```
!**/my-site/components/com_content/*
```

Woo! 75 untracked files. Amazing. Am I an idiot or what is this? The most strange behavior I ever seen.

Now... what's happening here? I just want to unignore a single file into ignored folder.

### Update

Yeah, I know, I can do something like this

```
!**/my-site/components/com_content/
**/my-site/components/com_content/*.*
**/my-site/components/com_content/controllers/*
**/my-site/components/com_content/helpers/*
**/my-site/components/com_content/models/*
!**/my-site/components/com_content/models/articles.php
**/my-site/components/com_content/views/*
```

but I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not ignore a file in a sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170137/not-ignore-a-file-in-a-sub-directory)

maybe something like this? been a while since i've used git but i think you should be able to get it from the link.

```
!**/my-site/components/
!**/my-site/components/com_content/
!**/my-site/components/com_content/models/
**/my-site/components/*
!articles.php
```

*EDIT*
How about:

```
!**/my-site/components/
**/my-site/components/*
!com_content/models/articles.php
```

Comment: Don't work. I've read your link, so it seems that I just can't because git don't even know that subdirectory exists.

Comment: Still nothing. I've come up with unignoring the whole `com_content` folder and then ignore all subfolders explicitlely, but this is very... sad solution.

Comment: I agree but if it works, whats a few extra lines in a text file? =\

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't own Joomla framework, and if they decide to rebuild their files structure, I will be screwed. Plus that raises the complicity and bus factor. That's not a programmer's way =) Thanks for help tho.